# eclipse import google-play-services_lib display error in values

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library

import google-play-services_lib to my workspace but giving error in all values folder
i had clean project change Google API, add google-play-services.jar file, restart eclipse but yet errors[image]

in console display error like below

```
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\ads_attrs.xml:10: error: Attribute "adSize" has already been defined
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\ads_attrs.xml:17: error: Attribute "adSizes" has already been defined
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\ads_attrs.xml:20: error: Attribute "adUnitId" has already been defined
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:4: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_dark_text_default is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:4: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:5: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:5: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:6: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:6: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:7: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:7: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:8: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_light_text_default is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:8: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:9: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_light_text_pressed is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:9: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:10: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_light_text_disabled is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:10: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:11: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_light_text_focused is already defined.
    [2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:11: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:12: error: Resource entry common_signin_btn_default_background is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:12: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_colors.xml:13: error: Resource entry common_action_bar_splitter is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\colors.xml:13: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\strings.xml:6: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_install_title is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_strings.xml:21: Originally defined here.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\strings.xml:10: error: Resource entry common_google_play_services_install_text_phone is already defined.
[2014-05-23 11:54:22 - GPSService] D:\AndroidTool\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values\common_strings.xml:25: Originally defined here.
```

Comment: Have u given target version?

Comment: in library ther is not target version but yet as per your suggestion i had put it but yet displaying errors

Comment: have u checked properties in application??

Comment: @krishna project.properties in lib na?

Comment: Right click project- properties - Android - Select Target version

Comment: @IamDeveloper yes it's change now it's 4.4.2 google api

Comment: @IamDeveloper Not yet

Comment: Right click project- properties - Java build path

Comment: @krishna that's i had do check all lib also but same prob\

Comment: please post ur console message or error message

Comment: check path for the libraries whether it is correct or not?

Comment: or else delete your android dependencies and then clean and run the project..

Comment: @IamDeveloper i had some one two error it's display attribute already define..
libraries path is my workspace

Comment: @krishna delete dependecies and clean but yet same

Comment: Right click on project-Android tools and fix project properties

Comment: have you added library from properties-android-add??

Comment: @krishna that not work it's display some attribute are already define but how it's possible it's library project so.

Comment: @krishna this google-play-services_lib is itself library there is no need to add that it's just check as library

Comment: ok then  you must try to import it again

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you figured out the solution yet?

Comment: @Paladine no yet not but old google play service working for me so i m using that u can vote me if you have sme issue

Comment: Now google play servicer new version revision 18 import successfully version 17 has only problem

Comment: @PankajAndroid Solved the issue?

Comment: @MRX yes recently google service update and import that library work fine no issue

Answer (score 5):

Try to import library without adding to workspace. In my case that was a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue for colors.xml, it was because this file does not seem to be present anymore.
The colors it contains before are now declared in common_colors.xml.
Perhaps you want to delete your previous Google Play Services folder from your project to do a fresh copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import library from same folder where project exist without adding to workspace.

Answer (score 1):

This error cropped up for me when I was trying to update my version of google play services. The full process that worked for me was to delete the original project, remove all references to the play services project from my other projects in the workspace (i.e. open the project properties and remove play services as a referenced Android library project), then import the play services project. I can't remember if I did `Import Existing Projects into Workspace` or `Import Existing Android Code`.

The trick that got rid of the "originally defined here" errors was to first remove the existing old references to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and it was caused by some conflicting resource values in the extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib folder.

Since admob and analytics are now merged into Google Play Services, what I did was uninstall those items from the SDK Manager as well as the Google Play Services. Then I just reinstalled Google Play Services. That ended up removing the duplicate resource values and my build succeeded after that.

Comment: how you had uninstall those items? and if i want latest google play service with admob and analitics then?

Comment: I uninstalled them via the SDK Manager. Unchecked them in the extras category. Admob is deprecated by play services, so you can safely uninstall that and I believe Analytics was also folded into GPS, so you probably don't need that either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy entire `$SDK\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services` folder including `source.properties` file

Comment: Thanks for reply but new updated google play service working fine no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old project and than add the new one, otherwise some files are not removed, which can cause problems like this one